# adjustpan is not working on nexus 7 or any device with kitkat os

Tags: android, cordova

I am using cordova 1.9.0 and jquery-mobile 1.8.3 and my application has some input text boxes and on pop up of soft keyboard , the screen is not resizing for devices which have android sdk kitkat . what can be the problem ?

Comment: Adjustpan doesn't resize, it moves the app up so the cursor stays on screen (if needed).  Do you mean adjustresize isn't working?

Comment: yes even when on screen keyboard pops up . the app is not resizing .. and is behaving in a way that the keyboard is coming on top of input box and i am not able to see what i am typing .